# Chrome Extension androidpublisher packageName

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I have developed a Chrome Extension using in-app-purchases. I've published it to Google Web Store.

Now I want to use the androidpublisher API to validate purchases made:

https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v2/applications/**{packageName}**/inappproducts

I am unable to find out what my **packageName** is.

There are numerous examples for Apps, not Extensions. Apps seem to have packageName declared somewhere, often looking something like 'com.mystuff.myproduct'.

I cannot find any such reference anywhere related to my extension, not in the manifest file, Google Web Store, Google Dashboard, Google Payments Center or Google Play Console. Nowhere! All I have is the Id that looks like 'abcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdef'.

Does anybody know?

Answer (score 1):

Chrome extensions are not android apps. Chrome extensions don't have package names. Check the [In-App Payments with Payments Merchant Account and the Chrome Web Store API](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/payments-iap) for the supported methods and API calls.